# Only allow CSV Files in Kendo Upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-upload

How can I restrict Kendo upload to CSV files?

Razor:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
        .Name("import-file")
        .Multiple(false)
        .ShowFileList(true)
        .Async(a => a
            .Save("Save", "Import")
            .Remove("Remove", "Import")
            .AutoUpload(false)
        )
        .Events(events => events.Select("App.Import.select"))
    )
```

Javascript:

```
 Import: {
    select: function (event) {
        $.each(event.files, function (index, value) {
            if (value.extension !== '.csv') {
                alert("not allowed!");
            }

            console.log("Name: " + value.name);
            console.log("Size: " + value.size + " bytes");
            console.log("Extension: " + value.extension);
        });
        var breakPoint = 0;
    }    
}
```

My Idea is to remove the file in the select event. How can I accomplish this?

Regards,
Marko

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/upload#events-select), what you should do is to cancel the event (`e.preventDefault()`).

[image]

So, since you are not allowing multiple file selection, what you should do is:

```
select: function (event) {
    var notAllowed = false;
    $.each(event.files, function (index, value) {
        if (value.extension !== '.csv') {
            alert("not allowed!");
            notAllowed = true;
        }

        console.log("Name: " + value.name);
        console.log("Size: " + value.size + " bytes");
        console.log("Extension: " + value.extension);
    });
    var breakPoint = 0;
    if (notAllowed == true) e.preventDefault();
}
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/n5Y2s/1/